# Vue update dom every second, Simple Clock

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to make simple clock, I created the project using `@vue/cli` and currently have two files `App.vue` which is just a host/view for other components,and `clock.vue` component imported inside `App.vue` and the clock component code is as follows.

```
    <template>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="vertical">
          {{ hours }}
          <br />
          {{ minutes }}
          <br />
          {{ seconds }}
          <br />
          {{ amPm }}
        </div>
        <div class="horizontal">
          {{ hours }} : {{ minutes }} : {{ seconds }} : {{ amPm }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script lang="ts">
    import Vue from "vue";

    const date = new Date();
    export default Vue.extend({
      data() {
        return {
          hours: date.getHours(),
          minutes: date.getMinutes(),
          seconds: date.getSeconds(),
          amPm: "AM",
          interval: 0
        };
      },
      mounted() {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.updateClock, 1000);
      },
      beforeDestroy() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      },

      methods: {
        updateClock(): void {
          this.hours = date.getHours();
          this.minutes = date.getMinutes();
          this.seconds = date.getSeconds();
          this.amPm = this.hours >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
          this.hours = this.hours % 12 || 12;
          this.minutes = this.minutes < 10 ? 0 + this.minutes : this.minutes;
          this.hours = this.hours < 10 ? 0 + this.hours : this.hours;
        }
      }
    });
    </script>

    <style lang="scss">
    .contaienr {
      display: flex;
    }
    </style>
```

I want the clock to update every second with `setInterval` but it's still not working for some reason. Checked a lot of answers on stackoverflow and all of them use `setInterval`.

Comment: You have a typo in your `style` tag - should be `.container` not `.contaienr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new date once and referencing this every second (it never changes) - instead, create a new reference within `updateClock` and remove the other one:

```js
methods: {
  updateClock(): void {
    const date = new Date(); // create a new reference here

    this.hours = date.getHours();
    this.minutes = date.getMinutes();
    this.seconds = date.getSeconds();
    this.amPm = this.hours >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
    this.hours = this.hours % 12 || 12;
    this.minutes = this.minutes < 10 ? 0 + this.minutes : this.minutes;
    this.hours = this.hours < 10 ? 0 + this.hours : this.hours;
  }
}
```